# Remove "Acuttweather.com" widget on the top of the home page

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow

I have purchased LG K8 phone.Can you tell me how to remove the front screen's "Acuttweather.com" widget on the top of the home page?

Android ver: 6.0

Comment: Does this not work ? https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-205452/

Comment: Oh..Thanks a lot.It worked.Can you put that steps as an answer? Then I can close this post :) @beeshyams

Comment: Posted as requested - that was the first hit on Google :) you may consider accepting by ticking the green Arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remove Items from Home Screen - LG K8 V](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-205452/)

> From a Home screen, touch and hold the item (e.g., widget, shortcut, folder, etc.).
>
> Drag the item onto "Remove" trash icon or "Uninstall" trash icon (located at the top) then release